# Aggregating character rows, split and repeat

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I have this character dataset,

```
var1 <- c("10300010118,",
          "1030002,",
          "1030003,",
          "103000405, 0512,",
          "103000612, 0717,",
          "10310010618,",
          "103100221,",
          "103100315,",
          "103100412, 0517",
          "103100612,0729,",
          "14510010517,",
          "145100212,",
          "1451003,",
          "145100465, 0588,",
          "145100651, 0777,")
```

I would like to split it into columns considering,

- Every 5 lines should be in a single row. In this example, we have 15
  rows. That means the desired output should be 3 rows.
- The first character of every five rows (1 in this example) should be the first column, the next 4 characters in five rows (0300 for instance) will be the second row and the rest would be in the last row.

The resulting data should look like this,

```
> data
    v1 v2    v3
1   1  0300  010118, 02, 03, 0405, 0512, 0612, 0717,
2   1  0310  010618, 0221, 0315, 0412, 0517, 0612, 0729,
3   1  4510  010517, 0212, 03, 0465, 0588, 0651, 0777,
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  Create a `data_frame` with 'var1', `separate` into three columns based on the position index, remove the `,` at the end of the string in 'v3' column, create a grouping column with `gl` to group the lines in every 5 lines, grouped by the 'grp', 'v1', and 'v2', `summarise` the 'v3' by `paste`ing the elements of 'v3' into a single string

```
library(tidyverse)
data_frame(var1) %>% 
    separate(var1, into = paste0('v', 1:3), sep= c(1, 5)) %>% 
    mutate(v3 = str_remove(v3, ",$")) %>%
    group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 5, n())), v1, v2) %>%
    summarise(v3 = toString(v3)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  v1    v2    v3                                       
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>                                    
#1 1     0300  010118, 02, 03, 0405, 0512, 0612, 0717   
#2 1     0310  010618, 0221, 0315, 0412, 0517, 0612,0729
#3 1     4510  010517, 0212, 03, 0465, 0588, 0651, 0777
```

---

Or we can do this in `base R` by creating a delimiter at the positions mentioned and then use `read.csv`

```
df1 <- read.table(text= sub("^(.)(.{4})(.*),?$", "\\1-\\2-\\3", var1), 
    sep="-", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, col.names = paste0("v", 1:3))
df1$grp <- as.integer(gl(nrow(df1), 5, nrow(df1)))
aggregate(v3 ~ ., df1, FUN = toString)[-3]
```

Comment: Thanks. It just works and special thanks for the explanation.